# Built in way to convert from screen coordinates to image coordinates?

Tags: konvajs

I have an app where users can scale and position images in a number of ways.  They can drag an entire layer of images around, scale that layer, drag around individual images inside the layer, and scale those individual images.

For some unrelated functionality, I need to generate the image coordinates that a user is pointing to on a given image (ie (0,0) for the top left & (width,height) for the bottom right), independent of how much it has been moved around and scaled.  Is there a built in method for tranforming an absolute mouse position to it's relative position on an image (and vice versa) that takes into account any scaling/panning?  I have started building my own methods for this tranformation but before I got too deep I wanted to see if it was already built in somewhere that I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Konva` doesn't have such methods yet. You have to implement them manually.

You can subscribe to this related issue: https://github.com/konvajs/konva/issues/303

Comment: Thanks for the info, I implemented a workable solution and will keep an eye on the issue!